# Pygame can't draw above screen

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, drawing

I'm working on learning how to utilize pygame's graphics stuff, and have run into an issue while making a snowflake generator thing. What it does is it randomly selects a part of the screen and puts a white circle there, and adds that circle's coordinates to a list to redraw the next frame. The snowflakes all move down at a constant rate, and once they hit the bottom, I want to redraw them slightly above the screen. When I try to do this, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Pokemon game\Pokemon-game\snowflakes stuff.py", line 33, in <module>
    y_coord=randint(-10, -50)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 199, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (-10,-49, -39)
[Finished in 1.7s with exit code 1]
```

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from random import *

pygame.init()

Black=(0, 0, 0)
White=(255, 255, 255)

size=(800, 600)
game_display=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Snowflakes')

closed=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

snow=[]

while not closed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            close=True
    game_display.fill(Black)
    x_coord=randint(0, 800)
    y_coord=randint(0, 600)
    snow.append([x_coord, y_coord])
    for i in range(len(snow)):
        pygame.draw.circle(game_display, White, snow[i], 2)
        snow[i][1]+=1
        if snow[i][1]>600:
            x_coord=randint(0, 800)
            y_coord=randint(-10, -50)
            snow[i][0]=x_coord
            snow[i][1]=y_coord
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation for randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) says, the return value will be a value greater than the first argument but smaller then the second. Since a number cannot be greater than -10 and smaller than -50, it throws you an error. Just switch `randint(-10, -50)` to `randint(-50, -10)` and you should be fine.